# Что делает амперсанд в логический условиях?

Tags: c

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <locale.h>
int i = 0, value = 0;
int main()
{
setlocale(0, "Russian");
char s[] = "...рандомные...слова...и...многоточия..."; 
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
{
    if (s[i] == '.' & s[i + 1] == '.') // <<< --- Что делает амперсанд в этой строке?
        s[i] = ' ';
}
puts(s);

    for (i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == 0) { break; }
        value++;
    }
    printf("Количество символов в строке = %d\n", value-10);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
```

Не просто же в строке с "if" ищутся два символа подряд?

Comment: Логическое И. Да верно ищутся 2 символа подряд

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (s[i] == '.' & s[i + 1] == '.') //Что делает амперсанд в этой строке?
```

Это операция "бинарное И". В данном случае это будет работать почти как логическое И, но так писать не стоит:

```
if (s[i] == '.' && s[i + 1] == '.') //так правильнее, условие выполнится только если оба подвыражения истинны
```

В современном С++ можно использовать синоним:

```
if (s[i] == '.' and s[i + 1] == '.')
```

Эту строку следует понимать так: "если i-й и i+1й символ одновренменно равны точке - '.' заменить i-й символ на пробел."